# Is there a way to get a channel name?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is there a way to get a channel’s name? I’m creating a bot that will log created and deleted channels and I want to be able to get the channel name and not the ID.

I’ve checked the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel) and there is no name property, so I was wondering if there was a way around this.

My current code is this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('channelCreate', channel => {
    const logChannel = channel.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'log');
    if (!logChannel) return;
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#64cd6d')
        .setAuthor('Channel created')
        .setTitle('I want to put the channel name here');
        .setDescription(channel)
        .setFooter(`ID: ${channel.id}`)
        .setTimestamp();
    logChannel.send(embed);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a [guildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel), you can simply use `channel.name`.
For your **channelDelete** event it works also like this.

What you've checked are **all** channels that are on Discord. So this means any textchannel (direct message or Discord server) and there you are just limited with the properties and methods.